# UIEdgeInsets resizing Back button

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem, uiappearance

I'm trying to customize the back button of a UINavigationBar using the iOS 5 UIAppearance API. The image I want to use is this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ce83rw0e3vs9dwo/bt-back.png and the code is the following:

```
// Customize back button items differently
UIEdgeInsets aInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
UIImage *buttonBack30 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bt-back.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:aInset];
UIImage *buttonBack24 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bt-back.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:aInset];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBack30 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBack24 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

Now, the output of that code is the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE7nB.png

I know I have to set the UIEdgeInsets to a proper value, but I've being reading the documentation and it seems that it's only possible to preserve the edges and not the center, witch seems to be the thing I need to do.

Is there any way to preserve the center and not the edges? If not, what's the dimensions I have to generate the PNG so iOS doesn't stretch it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the method

```
- (UIImage *)backButtonBackgroundImageForState:(UIControlState)state
    barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

to retrieve the back button's background image, retrieve its `size` property, and then use this for the size to make your custom image?

Comment: No, it didn't work... had to set the back button manually every time